# What are all the possible first arguments to `\setbeamerfont`?

Tags: beamer, fonts

I have searched in the [user guide](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) for the string `\setbeamerfont`, but the only thing I could find was a description that said `\setbeamerfont{some beamer element}`.

Where can I find a listing of all beamer elements whose font can be set using this command?

In this particular case, I am trying to find the beamer font for "normal" text.

Comment: Search for `/-Font` instead.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are three macros for setting the font:

```
\usefonttheme[settings] {font theme}
\setbeamerfont * {beamer element}{attributes}
\usebeamerfont * {beamer element}
```

The attributes are something like `size`, `shape`, etc

The predefined `beamer fonts` are

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the source of this table? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Lars, it is a simple `longtable`

Comment: Thanks Herbert, I mean not the source as in source code, but the source of the information in it :)

Comment: Oh, it's in "Presentations with LaTeX"

Answer (score 4):

There is no definitive list of fonts because font names are arbitrary. You can use whatever(*) name you like in `\setbeamerfont{}{}` and beamer will create this font for you and you'll be able to use it afterwards with `\usebeamerfont{}`.

You can find an overview of the font names used in the default themes (which come with beamer) in the beamer cheat sheet from [https://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~masson/latex/Beamer-appearance-cheat-sheet.pdf](https://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/%7Emasson/latex/Beamer-appearance-cheat-sheet.pdf) :

[image]

Just be aware that there are many more themes out there and some of them will use their own font names.

(*) within the limits of reasonable letters and symbols which won't make latex throw up