# Beamer warsaw make font bold on all frames

Tags: beamer, fonts

When using beamer with the warsaw theme, how can one set the text on all frames to appear in boldface?

Here is an MWE, I want text on both the slides to be in boldface.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color,soul}

\author{author}
\title{title}
\institute{institute} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
text on this slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test one this slide
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: At this stage I do not have a solution to the problem to add a MWE.

Comment: The MWE does not have to contain a solution, but even if it just contains `\documentclass{beamer}`, the theme and a frame users wiling to help you can just copy paste it and start solving your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just choose which elements of a frame you want to be bold.

`\AtBeginDocument{\bfseries\selectfont}` makes the normal text bold.

More options can be found at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183053/36296

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\AtBeginDocument{\bfseries\selectfont} % normal text 
\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\bfseries} 
\setbeamerfont{structure}{series=\bfseries} 
\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry author}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry title}{series=\bfseries}

\author{author}
\title{title}
\institute{institute} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
text on this slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test one this slide
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```