# How do I set a small default font size for table in Beamer?

Tags: tables, beamer, fontsize

This post, [shrinking tables for presentations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5067/shrinking-tables-for-presentations), gives a solution, using `\small` or `\tiny` after the `\begin{table}`. How do I make it effect for all tables, globally?

I also checked this post, [What are all the possible first arguments to `\setbeamerfont`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183052/what-are-all-the-possible-first-arguments-to-setbeamerfont), and there is no option like `table` for `\setbeamerfont`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\tiny}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    abc

    \begin{table}
    abc
    \end{table}

    abc

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

(for older versions of `beamer`, `\usepackage{etoolbox}` might be required)