# How to set the default font in a beamer sty-file?

Tags: beamer, fonts, templates, default

I'm currently creating a beamer sty-file and want the style to change the default font. I tried the following without success:

1. `\setmainfont` has no effect.
2. For `\setbeamerfont{<type>}{family=XXX}` works for types listed e.g. here [What are all the possible first arguments to `\setbeamerfont`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183052/what-are-all-the-possible-first-arguments-to-setbeamerfont). But which type to use for the default font? According to the beamer user guide `normal text` has no effect yet.

So, how to set the default font in a beamer sty-file?
If this matters: I'm using Luatex.